# Контролируемая переадресация вызова asterisk

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

Появилась необходимость создать контролируемую переадресацию вызовов

Суть задачи в том, чтобы соединить двух оператора и абонента, по следующей логике

1. Оператор 1 разговаривает с клиентом
2. Ставит вызов на удержание
3. Набирает очередь
4. В очереди отвечает Оператор 2
5. Оператор 1 и Оператор 2 соединяют ся
6. Оператор 1 отключается от вызова и Оператор 2 соединяется с клиентом. Клиент снимается с удержания

Настроек стандартных не нашла. Настроила только очередь со статичными пользователями. При переадресации вызова Оператор 1 сейчас отключается